# How to Improve OS performance when used from USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-mint, usb-boot

I have a Linux Mint 14 (MATE) .ISO installed on an 8GB [Kingston DTSE9](http://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/products?model=dtse9h) USB drive.

Booting takes about 1 or 2 minutes, which seems pretty normal for that kind of thing as far as I can tell.

When running the OS though, the whole system seems to halt for about 20-30 seconds about once every minute or so. Its maddening.

I can move my mouse, and interact with already open windows, but I can't open new programs or open the MATE menu during that 20-30 seconds. It's really hard to get stuff done like that, so I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to smooth it out.

I wouldn't even mind if a solution made the system slower, as long as it was consistently slow and didn't have the fits and starts.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a different USB stick to rule it out as the cause?

Comment: Nope, but its new, it boots fine, it operates fine when I've read and wrote to it. I see no reason it'd be a cause.

Comment: Which version and what speed of USB port is it attached to?  Does it work any differently when used with a different computer?

Comment: Version 2, and I did boot it up on a laptop (this one is a desktop), but didn't really use it enough to know for sure. I'll have to check that

Comment: USB 2.0 can't multi task. 

It chokes as soon as it is asked to do more than 2 things. 

Some chipsets are worse than others, as are some flash drives no doubt.

Perhaps try it on different PC's, try different usb key. Try a USB 3.0 card... but yeah, i've been disapointed with live USB systems more than once

Comment: Thanks for the info Michael, sounds like its likely the fact its on USB2